# How to Create New Document Set with Multiple Periods Using SharePoint Designer

Tags: designer-workflow, document-set

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a Document Set via a SharePoint 2010 workflow in SharePoint Online. The workflow does actually create the Document Set but doesn't go past the first period "." in the variable that I'm using.
For example:

```
Project ID = 1234.test.001
Docset Name = 1234.test
```

**Question:** How do I, or is there a way, to ensure that the full Project ID be used when creating the Docset via the workflow?

Thanks
D